# Laravel 4 Model class not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I just created a simple app in Laravel 4 and when I create a model, I get an exception that it's not found.

```
// /app/models/Worker.php:
<?php

class Worker extends Eloquent {}
```

And then in the Controller

```
var_dump(Worker::find(1));
```

This gives me Error: Class 'Worker' not found. What am I doing wrong? This used to work in Laravel 3 and also watching the screencasts it seems like this should work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Anytime you create a new class file in L4 run this command.

```
php composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: "Just great". And I thought there's surely something that I did wrong. Now it works. I think I remember hearing that on one of the nettuts screencasts, but, naturally forgot. But now I got another problem, which I'll post another question for :).

Comment: Here's the other problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284854/laravel-4-eloquentfind-doesnt-work

Comment: I think you've got them mixed up.. composer dump-autoload..  php artisan dump-autoload

Comment: so... depending on the context of which you setup composer, This could in fact be php composer.phar dump-autoload, php artisan clear-compiled, or composer dump-autoload (globally installed composer)

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two commands to get the autoload started:

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

and

```
$ php artisan dump-autoload
```

Seems composer dump-autoload is to let composer create autoloads as defined in the composer.json files. And php artisan dump-autoload glues all the composer dump-autoloads ( also from vendors and workbenches ) together.