# Laravel 4: Eloquent::find() doesn't work

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-4

So I have a simple, empty Eloquent class: `class Worker extends Eloquent {}`.
Then in the controller I write: `Worker::find(1);` and I get an exception, saying that the SQL is incorrect:

```
select * where `id` = ?
```

Obviously, the from SQL clause is missing.

Oh, I downloaded the Laravel 4 for this app today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Laravel 4 you have to set a table property

`protected $table = 'foo';`

Comment: This sucks! What was wrong before? Ah, the simplicity slowly fading into complexity.

Comment: Another one for you maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14285182/laravel-4-where-is-to-array

Comment: Before it pluralized the Class name to give a table name. I have no idea why that was taken out but I did like it haha.

Also to help on your quest is some prelim docs https://github.com/laravel/docs

Comment: Yeah, I know, it was the default and you could still overwrite it if you wanted => best of both worlds.

Comment: As an FYI if you upgrade to beta 2 the table recognition and pluralizor is back

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, you have to specifically set a `$table` property on the model. Taylor has [mentioned here](https://gist.github.com/4111700#comment-602817) that the old way of doing things (a default table name as the plural of the model's name) may be returning. There just isn't a good composer package for pluralising, so the L3 code may be ported.