# Laravel 4: where is to_array()?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Man, this is getting frustrating!

In Laravel 4, using Eloquent, this works: `var_dump(Worker::find(1));`. But if I try to use `to_array()`, it falls apart: `var_dump(Worker::find(1)->to_array());`. This throws the following exception:

call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder' does not have a method 'to_array'

Comment: Did you see the new (beta) docs? http://four.laravel.com/

Comment: No, I didn't. This will prevent many headaches :). Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Method in Laravel 4 are now camelCased

```
var_dump(Worker::find(1)->toArray());
```

Comment: Ah, again! Completely forgot!