# Laravel model not found

Tags: laravel-5

We have a model `App\Models\Tag`. In a helper class we're doing:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Models\Tag;


class Helper {

    /**
    * Get tag
    *
    **/
    public static function tag($path){

            return Tag::where('path', '=', $path)->first();

    }


}
```

This gives error:

```
FatalErrorException in Model.php line 780: 

Class 'Tag' not found
```

Even using `App\Models\Tag::where('path', '=', $path)->first()` gives an error:

```
FatalErrorException in Helper.php line 15: 

Class 'App\Helpers\App\Models\Tag' not found
```

What's most strange is that we can use `App\Models\Tag` from controller without a problem. So, problem seems to be on this helper class and not the model. Any idea?

**Tag.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tag extends Model {

        // database table
        protected $table = 'tags';

}

?>
```

**Edit 1**

The model **Tag.php** was manually added instead of using `artisan`. So, there's a chance it's missing from classes map. From the suggestion on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35142715/1008916 we tried `composer dump-autoload -o` but that didn't help.

**Edit 2**

We eventually traced the issue to a different model related to Tag.php. The lines of code causing the problem were:

```
        $tag = Tag::where('path', '=', $path)->first();
        if ($tag == null) {
            $tagLet = TagLet::where('path', '=', $path)->first();
            if ($tagLet != null) {
                $tag = $tagLet->tag;
            }
        }
```

When  a model throws an error Laravel does not give line number where the error occurred, so we identified the 1st occurrence of Tag as cause while the real cause was last occurrence (`$tag = $tagLet->tag;`).

TagLet.php had:

```
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Tag');
}
```

As suggested by @Rodrane & @SauminiNavaratnam the solutions is to use 'App\Models\Tag' instead of 'Tag'

```
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tag');
}
```

Comment: try this `use App\Models\Tag as Tag; `

Comment: Try using `\App\Models\Tag::where('path', '=', $path)->first()`, you need to add `\\` in the front

Comment: @Rodrane `use App\Models\Tag as Tag` doesn't work as well

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam using `\App\Models\Tag::where('path', '=', $path)->first()` changes the error to `Class 'Tag' not found`

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba Can you also add the `Tag` model class code. Double check the namespace & class name in the `Tag.php` model file

Comment: try `\App\Tag::where('path', '=', $path)->first() ` if you used artisan to create model it is not in models folder then

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam added model class to question

Comment: @Rodrane model exists in models folder but we manually added it instead of using `artisan`. So, I think problem could be it doesn't appear in classes map. We tried using `composer dump-autoload` but that didn't help.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba Model looks fine for me. I hope you added the your custom helper file in the `composer.json` autoload. This is all comes top of my head

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam the helper class works with other models except this one. I have added more details to the question on likely cause of the problem. The challenge might be how to get **Tag** in the classes map since it appears to be missing there.

Comment: @MugomaJ.Okomba This may be a stupid question to ask, did copy the model file to your server?

Comment: @SauminiNavaratnam not sure I understand the question but the model is in 'models' folder. I am doing tests from local.

Comment: Please show composer.json file

Answer (score 0):

Check where located your Tag.php file, I think it inside app directory, if that change namespase from App\Model, to App. If not check your folder structures and namespases.