# Model Class not found error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Using Laravel 5.4, I am getting this error on view whenever I call my method it shows on screen

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Models\Chat\User' not found
```

Hierarchy of my project :

```
Controllers
    - ChatMessageController
Models
   -Chat
        -message.php
   -User.php
```

and here's my controller class code :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Chat;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Chat\Message;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class ChatMessageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $messages = message::with(['user'])->latest()->limit(100)->get();
      return response()->json($messages,200);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're going to want to change `message.php` to `Message.php`, by the way.

Comment: Where is your model App\Models\Chat\User or App\Models\User ?

Comment: Can you show the Message class? I suspect there is a missing import there which get triggered by the eager loading here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.0 - Model Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350232/laravel-5-0-model-class-not-found)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `message.php`, probably you forgot to add: `use App\Models\User;`.

So, it is trying to find User in the wrong space.

Comment: @QaimRaza Please also observe the case of the filename. As suggested, it should be changed from `message.php` to `Message.php` to ensure it also works on a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: Thanks @localheinz, I also changed that.