# php artisan serve not working, error ""In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found""

Tags: laravel-5

when I run php artisan serve it gives the following error.

"In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

Class 'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider' not found"

Tried to run **composer install** but it gives the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Model Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350232/laravel-model-class-not-found)

Comment: It not duplicate, I have a problem with ImageServiceProvider. PHP ARTISAN SERVE is not running, COMPOSER commands are also not working.