# Laravel: Class "App\Models\Device" not found in web.php (only in production)

Tags: php, laravel, debian

i'm trying to make an example project to learn laravel. I set up the project on my computer and everything worked fine: I have my `web.php` that routes `/` to a view, but before that it collects devices so it can show you some data.

I decided to try and host it on a Debian AWS instance so I cloned my repo in `/var/www/`, migrated the database, wrote the `.env`, `composer install`, set folder ownership to admin user and permissions to storage and bootstrap.

Once i configured nginx i tried it by navigating to the url and the answer was `Class "App\Models\Device" not found.`

I checked the namespaces, file names, I even read that debian is a sucker for caps sensitivity so i double checked every capital letter in every name and since app folder is named app and not App i even tried to import it as `app\Models\Device` but to no avail.

I also tried with `composer dump-autoload` as many on SO suggested, but nothing changed at all.

Am i missing something?

Device.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Device extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;


    protected $fillable = [
        'serial',
        'livello_acqua',
        'umidita',
        'temperatura',
        'livello_mangime',
        'stato_rele_1',
        'stato_rele_2',
        'stato_rele_3',
        'stato_rele_4',
        'descrizione',
    ];

    public static function findBySerial($serial){
        return Device::where('serial', $serial)->get();
    }

    public static function findByUser($id){
        return Device::where('user_id', $id)->get();
    }

}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use app\Models\Device; //\app\Models\Device - App\Models\Device - \App\Model\Device
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    $devices = Device::all();

    return view('index')->with(['devices' => $devices]);
});
```

Structure:

```
- app
- - Models
- - - Device
- - ...
- ...
- routes
- - web.php
- ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i'm going nuts, i just tried again with `App\Models\Device` and got the error, re-changed it to `app\Models\Device` and got the error again and finally re-re-changed it to `App\Models\Device` and now it works...... have no idea why or how...

Answer (score -1):

Try to import it like so `use App\Models\Device;` instead of `use app\Models\Device;`

See this [link also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350232/laravel-model-class-not-found)