# Error to Retrieve data from database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a database name lrvesikhon and there is a table named 'person'. I created a model named 'Person' and also create a controller named 'PersonsController'. I also config the .env file. But some error occurs. The error:

[image]

My code -

PersonController -

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PersonsCotroller extends Controller
{
    public function index(){

        $person_list = Person::all();
        dd($person_list);
        
    }
}
```

Web -

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'PersonsCotroller@index');
```

Person Model -

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    protected $table = "person";
}
```

Comment: Try using some web IDE optimised for PHP. Its minor syntax miss to add "use" statement for the specified Model. Almost all regular IDE's will hint you for that miss.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Model class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350232/laravel-model-class-not-found)

Comment: If you're using a Laravel version lower than 8, include `use App\Person;` right after the `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write bellow code after use App\Http\Request;

```
use App\Models\Person;
```

If your model Person is not in Models directory change to use App\your-directory\Person;

Answer (score 0):

Your haven't hooked up the model class.

Add in your controller after `namespace App\Http\Controllers`

```php
use App\Models\Person;
```

Comment: It working. Thanks dear...